# Option fo changing colour of >, and more than one colour in a post?

Tags: support, feature-request

My eyes aren't great, ergo can there be an option to change the colour background for the gray box `>` be changed? For me, black on gray is hard.

> I prefer a lighter shade of **grey** here and want to choose it. Thank you to all.

Revised question: Possible to have more than one color shade in a post?

> Can this be light **blue**?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to choose it for yourself, you will need to add a custom CSS rule (search for "user css" + name of your preferred browser). For example,

```
blockquote {
  background-color: #f8f8f8 !important;
}
```

The default color is `#f0f0f0`, so the above is midway between that and white.

Comment: thanks. can you apprise me of my revised question too?

Comment: @tucker Google "light blue hexadecimal code" or something related to CSS